# Silverlight Datagrid bound with List Collection of Dictionary Items - Need Sorting

Tags: silverlight, list, datagrid, dictionary

Team,

I am trying to display a list of dictionary items in the silverlight datagrid.

I did a custom binding and the datagrid is already showing the data as expected.

But I am unable to sort the columns.

Here is an example.

Dictionay Item1 = { [key1,value1] , [key2, value2], [key3, value3] } 
Dictionay Item2 = { [key1,valueA] , [key2, valueB], [key3, valueC] } 
Dictionay Item3 = { [key1,valueX] , [key2, valueY], [key3, valueZ] }

My final Itemsource List = { Dictionary Item1,  Dictionary Item2 , Dictionary Item3}

SilverlightDatagrid.ItemsSource = My final Itemsource List;

All works fine and data shows in the table. But when I sort nothing happens.

I am not sure how to implement the custom sort function for this Dictionary List.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Thanks
Anand